# Transparency within radius using Shaders in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use a Shader material to create an area of transparency around my camera.
To achieve that, I'm checking if a vertex is inside a given radius, if so, I set its color with a custom opacity value < 1, such as 0.4.

This is working fine, but sometimes some transparent geometries are blocking the elements behind it. I took a look into the docs and some other similar question and figured out that usually we set the `depthWrite = false` and `transparent = true` only to transparent materials.

My problem is that I have only one material representing all my geometries but I want to set `depthWrite = false; transparent = true` to all vertices inside the radius and `depthWrite = true; transparent = false` to the ones outside it. Does anyone knows if this is something achievable or if there is another possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question! Hope this can help someone

It looks like it was not possible the way I was doing because I had only one material for the visible and transparent part.
Then, I decided to have 2 different shader materials rendering the same geometries, the visible and transparent ones, to set the depthWrite and transparent properties accordingly.
Also I discarded, using the fragment shader, the visible portion inside my transparent area and discarded the invisible one in the visible area.
It looks like it's working fine now